# how to test xmpp client?

Tags: unit-testing, automated-tests, xmpp, smack

I've developed a simple xmpp chat client (for Android, using asmack library). Now, I would like to test the client to see if it does what it is supposed to do (ie. fetch the list of contacts, refresh contact list, receive messages). Using smack library, I *assume* it is pretty much safe, but still...
How could I check if my fetched list of contacts is the one returned by the server? How to check if the presence status of certain contact is the correct one?
Regarding the usage of unit tests, I was thinking of mocking the server side and test the client side, but that doesn't seem of much use because I would like to test it with real server data.
  Is there some automated tool for this? Or would it be enough just to distribute the application to my friends and tell them to use it for a while and report any misbehaviors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll just have to trust aSmack. You could use logcat to investigate the XMPP stanzas returned by the server "by hand" and compare them to your client's behavior. You could also increase the verbosity on your server's log (if you have access) and compare that way. However, doing automated testing would require some sort of XMPP parser - but that's exactly what aSmack is. I'm sure the aSmack developers have already tested it thoroughly enough using their own methods.

Comment: that's what I thought. Thanks anyway.